# Only one value for $\sin^{-1}|\sin\theta|$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm supposed to prove that $\cos^{-1}x=2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2}}$.

Substituting x for $\cos(2\theta)$, the right-hand expression simplifies like;
$$2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\sin^2\theta}= 2\sin^{-1}|\sin\theta|$$

How does this work out to just $\theta$ when the sine's negative?

Comment: Also, can someone add the homework tag to math.stackexchange? I feel like I need it every other question.

Comment: Homework is supposed to be done by the student and noone else

Comment: There's been [a previous decision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what) against adding such a tag.

Comment: @Aditya I know direct questions aren't appreciated on Stack sites, but all I usually need is a particular concept or idea.

Comment: Ak19 posted the correct answer. $\theta$ will be in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principal range of $\arccos$ is $[0,\pi]$ and that of $\arcsin$ is $[\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$.
On letting $x = \cos(2\theta)$,  $-1\le x\le1 \Rightarrow 0\le2\theta\le\pi$

Now,  $0\le2\theta\le\pi \Rightarrow 0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ and in the first quadrant, $\sin$ is positive. So $|\sin\theta| = \sin\theta$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: choose the smallest range of $\theta\ge0$ you can that covers all $x\in[-1,\,1]$, then see what simplification that allows. In particular, you should find that not only can you drop the modulus signs, but that the $\arcsin$ then cancels the $\sin$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply $\cos$ to both sides. RHS gives $x$ and LHS too:

$$\cos\left(2\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2}}\right)=1-2\sin^2\left(\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2}}\right)=\\=1-2\left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)=x$$